# Flutter Image_picker, sqflite packages not working after app release and working well in debug mode

Tags: flutter, local-storage, release, sqflite, imagepicker

I have a problem after using `sqflite` and `image_picker` packages in the release only, which is I think the app not allowed to use the internal storage. I added `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` as an attribute to the `<application>` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`. also added a permission to use the internal storage. but the problem not resolved even after release production done in the google play console.
Can you help me?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you added the dependency in your pubspec.yaml under dependencies: or dev_dependencies: ?

Comment: Under dependencies